# How can I mix the ipywidget functions interact_manual and interactive_output

Tags: slider, jupyter, interactive

I would very much like to use the interact_manual functionality from the ipywidgets, because I am executing a time consuming function. At the same time, I like the interactive_output functionality, because it allows me to generate my widget in my source code and the just call one function that provides me with what I need to display.

Is there any good way how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The widgets should be simple float sliders, so nothing fancy.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can use the convenience functions (`interact_manual`, `interactive_output`, etc.) here. You have to build the interface yourself, which adds just a little complexity. Here's a simple example.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets

slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=5, min=1, max=10, step=1)
#Create your button.
button = widgets.Button(description="Go")
#Output field.
output = widgets.Output()

#function to handle input.
def showOutput(btn):
    output.clear_output()
    return_value = slider.value
    with output:
        print(return_value)

button.on_click(showOutput)

ui = widgets.HBox([slider, button, output])
ui
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of an undocumented way to do this. The implementation of interact and interact_manual is done almost completely via the interactive class functionality. The manual functionality is just a flag passed to it. So you can just do:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive
from IPython.display import display

my_widget = interactive(f, arg1=foo, arg2=bar, __manual=True)
display(my_widget)
```